# Save the output from a for each loop to an excel file

Tags: python

I'm relatively inexperienced at python. How would I save the output of my script to an excel file?

```html
import itertools

IDP = ['MS', 'GOOG', 'FB', 'LINK']
for L in range(0, len(IDP)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(IDP, L):
        print(subset)
```

Comment: check out pandas

Answer (score 0):

If you install pandas you can use the following code. To write the file to excel it can also ask for openpyxl or xlrd so you may have to install those also using pip

```
import pandas as pd 
import itertools
subset_list = []
IDP = ['MS', 'GOOG', 'FB', 'LINK']
for L in range(0, len(IDP)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(IDP, L):
        subset_list.append(subset)

df = pd.DataFrame(subset_list, columns=['enter the titles for your columns as a list'])

df.to_excel('subset.xlsx', index=False)
```